# Finding prime numbers within a given range of numbers

Tags: linux, shell, unix, git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What is wrong with this shell script program?
The program is about finding prime numbers in a given range of numbers.But it is also showing some of the numbers like 25,77 etc as prime numbers when I am giving the range 20 to 100.But when i am giving range as 20 to 30 then it is not showing 25 as prime number.Seems like nested for loops are running parallely when input size is large.

Here is the code:

```
read -p "Enter a Range of number (a to b) : " a b

echo "Prime numbers in the given range are :"

for ((i=$a;i<=$b;i++))
do

  max1=`echo | awk "{print sqrt($a)}"`
  max2=`printf %.0f "$max1"`
  maxCap=$max2
  check=0

  for (( j=2;j<=$maxCap;j++ ))
  do
    if [ $(($i%$j)) -eq 0 ]
    then
      check=1;
      break;
    fi
  done

  if [ $check -eq 0 ]
  then
        echo -n "$i   "
  fi

done
```

Comment: It is *not* showing 25 as a prime number? Is that really what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
max1=`echo | awk "{print sqrt($a)}"`
```

you are taking the square root of `a`, but it should be `i`:

```
max1=`echo | awk "{print sqrt($i)}"`
```

since you're looking for an upper bound on the divisors of `i`.

With that change the script seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look

```
    #!/bin/bash
    read -p "Enter a Range of number (a to b) : " a b

    echo "Prime numbers in the given range are :"
    for ((i=$a; i<=$b; i++))
    do
      max=$(bc <<< "scale=0; sqrt($i)")
      check=0

      for ((j=2; j<=$max; j++))
      do
        if (( $i % $j == 0))
        then
            check=1
            break
        fi
      done
      if [ $check -eq 0 ]
      then
          echo -n "$i   "
      fi
    done
```

Comment: Yeah!small variable mistake,already solved it.But thanks for your effort.